# How can I automatically populate HTML input boxes via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have created a HTML form that looks like this (I have entered the first three values).

Home team: Reds
Away team: Blues
Batted first: Reds
Batted second:
Fielded first:
Fielded second:

If the Red team batted first, I know the Blue team must have batted second, fielded first and that the Reds fielded second. Following this logic, I'd like to save my user some time and populate the remaining three fields automatically - with jQuery.

I'm guessing I need event listeners on the Home team, Away team, and Batted first input boxes. When these register as having content, I need the remaining empty boxes to be set with the appropriate values (following the logic above). Can anyone give me some ideas of where to start with this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get jQuery to populate these fields automatically via some
>   simple logic?

```
$("#yourinputfield").val("some value here");
```

You can use the above selector to change the value of an input field of type text

```
<input id="yourinputfield" type="text" value="" />
```